# C# ICMPV6 SocketException: Unknown error: -1

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ping, ipv6

I am making an IPv6 Traceroute program for a course. I am using MacOs 10.13.5 .NET Core SDK Version 2.1.302. I am unable to send an ICMP Packet to facebook.com. My wireless router and ISP both support IPv6. When I go to Advanced Network Information I see that I have an IPv6 address under the TCP/IP tab.

When I try to send a packet (or even an empty byte array) I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error: -1
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendTo(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendTo(Byte[] buffer, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint remoteEP)
```

I have the program connecting and working properly with IPv4. I am unable to use the Ping Class since the TTL option isn't supported with Unix. I was instructed to use the Dgram socket type when pinging using IPv4 due the Raw socket type being reserved.

My Code:

```
IPAddress[] ipv6Addresses = Array.FindAll(Dns.GetHostEntry("facebook.com").AddressList,a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);    

IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(ipv6Addresses[0], 80);
EndPoint ep = (iep);    

//Construct the packet
int packetSize = 0;
IcmpPacket packet = new IcmpPacket();
packet.Type = 8;
packet.SubCode = 0;
packet.CheckSum = UInt16.Parse("0");
packet.Identifier = UInt16.Parse("45");
packet.SequenceNumber = UInt16.Parse("0");    

int packetData = 32;
packet.Data = new byte[packetData];    

//Initialize the Packet Data
for (int a = 0; a < packetData; a++)
{
    packet.Data[a] = Convert.ToByte('a');
}    

packetSize = packetData + 8;    

//Serialize the packet
packet.GenerateCheckSum();    

Byte[] sendbuf = new Byte[packetSize];    

sendbuf = packet.Serialize();    

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.IcmpV6);
//socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.HopLimit, 1);
socket.SendTo(packet.Serialize(), packetSize, SocketFlags.None, iep);
```

Comment: What is ICMPv6 type 8?

Comment: @RonMaupinThe Intellisense in Visual Studio says 58

Comment: What is the ICMPv6 type and subtype you are sending? The ICMPv6 protocol number is 58. The IPv4 ICMP type 8 is an echo request, but that is not a valid ICMPv6 type.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ahh I see what you are saying. However, I do not think that is the source of this issue. If I send an empty and initialized byte array I still receive the same issue so I don't think the packet is the issue.

Comment: I'm not saying that I am curing your problem, I just happened to see that problem. I think you are overthinking this. Traceroute can be done with simple, empty UDP packets by increasing the TTL. You don't need to get involved in sending ICMP, just receiving ICMP error messages, looking for type 3 (Time Exceeded), Code 0 (Hop limit exceeded in transit).